# Where can I find the command line of a process started by systemd so I can debug it?

Tags: systemd

When a daemon foo is started by systemd, it fails as per the message below with the deamon complaining that invalid command line options have been used (via "journalctl -xe").

```
Feb 21 23:46:05 localhost systemd[1]: Starting The Foo Server...
-- Subject: Unit foo.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit foo.service has begun starting up.
Feb 21 23:46:05 localhost food[6709]: Usage: /usr/sbin/food [options]
```

How do you get systemd to log the command line being used so this error can be debugged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you configure systemd's logging to "debug" level you would see messages like:

```
"abc.service: Executing /bin/true arg arg arg"
```

`LogLevel=debug` is enough. Take a look at https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-system.conf.html.

The easiest way to get your changes applied would be restarting systemd.

Comment: I added "LogLevel=debug" to /etc/systemd/systemd.conf, and I used "systemctl daemon-reexec" to restart systemd.

This revealed the command line, however the line was a little difficult to find amongst other debug lines (it was definitely there).

This worked for me, thank you!